# Check if there are any Posts written with certain Post Format

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress theme and I need to **check if there are any Post written within certain Post Format**.

This is what I have in my **functions.php**

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio', 'gallery' ) );
```

And this little piece of code in **page template file**.

```
if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ) ){
    $post_formats = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    if ( is_array( $post_formats[0] ) ) {
        foreach ($post_formats[0]  as $post_format) { 
            echo '<a href="#">'.$post_format.'</a>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

So, currently I have **ALL Post Formats** displayed as links. What I need is to display **ONLY** the ones that have Posts with that Post Format assigned.

**Example:**

If there are no Posts with Post Format **Quote** assigned, don't display **quote** link.

I've tried to search the web  but without success. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$terms = get_terms("post_format");
             $count = count($terms);
             if ( $count > 0 ){
                 echo '<ul class="list-group">';
                 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                  if($term->count > 0)
                    echo '<a href="#">'.$term->name.'</a>'; 
                 }
                 echo '</ul>';
             }
```

Try This

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you so much @wordpresser !! It worked like a charm! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to Vote Up your answer but I marked it as accepted.

Comment: lol its okey .. and am glad it helped . `post-format` are taxonomies too :D